# adjective or adverb - She lay asleep

Tags: word-usage

> She lay asleep on the bed.

Is "asleep" an adverb or adjective in the sentence above?

I found that "asleep" can be used as an adverb in Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asleep). But I am not sure "asleep" is an adverb in the sentence above.

Comment: "Asleep" is an adjective functioning here as a predicative adjunct, i.e. it is a adjunct (modifier) in clause structure but it refers to the subject "she", hence predicative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we could argue that "asleep" describes *how* she lay in the bed, but it seems more logical to think of it as an *adjective* modifying "she".  It should be clear if we rephrase:

> She lay on the bed, asleep.

Compare this to something like:

> She lay **restlessly** on the bed, unable to sleep.

Where "restlessly" is an adverb describing how she lay.  We could alternately phrase this as an adjective:

> She lay **restless** on the bed, unable to sleep.

My impression is that "asleep" is only an adverb when used as part of the phrasal verb "fall asleep".

> After marching all night, the soldiers stumbled into the barracks and, almost immediately, **fell asleep** on their bunks.

Otherwise it seems always to be an adjective.